# Difference between final class and override final

Tags: c++, inheritance

The question is pretty simple, what's the difference in using `final` like this,

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual void Initialize() {}
};

class Derived final : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived() {}

    virtual void Initialize() override {}
};
```

And using `override final` like this,

```cpp
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}

    virtual void Initialize() {}
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() {}
    ~Derived() {}

    virtual void Initialize() override final {}
};
```

Comment: `final` on class says the class can't be derived from. `final` on method says the method cannot be further overridden in the derived class.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So its the same as saying `override final` to all the virtual functions in the derived class?

Comment: No. Such a class can still be derived from (it may not be particularly useful to do so, but still possible). In other words, `class FurtherDerived : public Derived{};` would compile in the second example, and produce an error in the first.

Comment: @D-RAJ `override final` is redundant. When overriding a virtual member function mark it `override` to override and allow further overriding in a more derived class, or mark it `final` to override and prevent further overriding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case locks the class. The following would cause an error:

```
class Derived2 : public Derived{};
```

The second forbids any class that inherits from it to redefine the `final`method.

Answer (score 1):

Using final on a method ensure that if another class inherits from that class, it is not allowed to override that method.

Using final on a class means that the class can not be derived from, at all.